# Additional return statement while finding minimum depth of a Binary Search Tree

Tags: recursion, binary-search-tree

Following is the code that I found online to find the minimum depth of a binary search tree:

```
public class Solution {
public int minDepth(TreeNode root) {
    if(root == null){
        return 0;
    }

    LinkedList<TreeNode> nodes = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();
    LinkedList<Integer> counts = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    nodes.add(root);
    counts.add(1);

    while(!nodes.isEmpty()){
        TreeNode curr = nodes.remove();
        int count = counts.remove();

        if(curr.left != null){
            nodes.add(curr.left);
            counts.add(count+1);
        }

        if(curr.right != null){
            nodes.add(curr.right);
            counts.add(count+1);
        }

        if(curr.left == null && curr.right == null){
            return count;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

}

What I do not understand is the extra return statement at the end- return 0. Why is this needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's for the case where the root isn't null, but it's the only node in the tree (the root is at depth 0). That return statement is needed because if the tree is empty, then something must be returned. It returns 0, because the depth is 0.

Comment: If there is only a root node w/ no children, then the while-loop will be executed once because nodes will not empty, the last if-statement in the while-loop will pass the check because root doesn't have any children, and count (which equals 1 at this point) will be returned. I do not believe that last return statement is reachable. Do share if you think of a tree that reaches that return statement.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to ghostofrasputin, the return statement is there because if the while condition is not met, then there is still a value to return.

Now the more important question, why do we need the last return if the program will never reach that return statement? (which I believe is this case for this)

Even though you are able to tell that the return statement wont be used, the compiler is not sophisticated enough to determine that, so it requires a return statement just in case the while loop is exited.

It's similar to the following code

```
public boolean getTrueOrFalse() {
    if(Math.random() < 1) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Though we know that this will always return true because `Math.random()` is always less than 1, the compiler isn't able to figure that out and thus the return statement is required if the if-statement is not met.